# In experience manager option to localize a page or component is disabled

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

When I open a page from 060 publication which is getting inherited from 040 publication, in xpm view, the option to localize the page is disabled. Same is the case with components which are also getting inherited from parent publication. When I open the same page using content management system, I am able to localize the page.

Does XPM provide you the option to localize the inherited pages and components ? If yes what can be possible cause of this error ?

Comment: Does the user have the permission to perform this from the Tridion CME?

Comment: Yes, Shiva user has the permission to localize it from Tridion CME.

Comment: By default, there are no restrictions in XPM stopping your above operation. Can you add a screen shot of the error with some test content? Is the content area grayed out or do you see a lock symbol etc.?

Answer (score 1):

When you open page in XPM, you will see lock on the top-left.

e.g check following screen. I hope page is not checked-out by any other user as you mentioned you are able to localize in CME.

[image]

Do you see this option in CME?

Comment: Yes Raj Kumar , I am able to localize the same page from CME and I don't see any lock within the XPM interface which clearly suggests that page has not been checkout by anybody.

Comment: lock mean its shared(coming from above) page. not directly created in your current publication, as your page is also at 040, you should see it.

Comment: My page is created in 040 but I am not able to see any lock when I am opening it from 060 in XPM view.

Comment: then your page might already localized or created in current pub only. please double check that  you are checking in right publications, also lock is just displayed below your publication name in XPm view

Comment: any success, please share your findings

Comment: Not yet I have double checked everything still I don't see that lock on the shared page.I will update you if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your SiteEdit settings? 
You can specify for each website publication the Components and Pages context. If your Pages context for 060 website publication is set to 040, then you would not see a lock icon as you would be directly editing the page in the parent publication (040).